# TypeError: messaging.getToken is not a function REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to add Cloud messaging feature in my project but facing this messaging.getToken() error which I am trying to solve from last 6 hours. Please help.
Thank you

== file firebase.js

```
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";

export const requestPermission = () => {
    Notification.requestPermission()
    .then( permission => {
        if (permission === 'granted') {
            messaging.getToken()
            .then(currToken => console.log(currToken))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
        }
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

== file main.js

```
<button onClick={requestPermission}>
    <p> New Task </p>
</button>
```

== file firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.3/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.3/firebase-messaging.js');

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "My api key",
  authDomain: "my domain name",
  projectId: "my project id",
  storageBucket: "my storage bucket address",
  messagingSenderId: "id",
  appId: "my app Id"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Firebase Cloud Messaging
export const messaging = getMessaging();


export default app;
```

I have followed the steps according to the firebase docs and also one video on youtube, but still have this error `TypeError: WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.messaging.getToken is not a function`

Comment: I got this error in the previous week. I think it may be related to the version. you can go with this latest documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive

Comment: @SajinSatheesan Thank you, will go through the doc for sure. Was your problem solved ?